# Is there a way to create a master password for user accounts created using C#.NET Identities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

Is there a way to add a master password which could be used to login into user accounts created using .NET Identities.  I would like an easy way for our system administrator to login to someone's account so they can see exactly what the customer would see when logged in.

One way would be to change the

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
```

method, so that it checks that the supplied password is indeed the master one, and if so use the supplied email address to grab the user, and then login normally with:

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, true, model.RememberMe);
```

Does this seem OK?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an actual word for this: **Impersonation.**

Here's a [link](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/user-impersonation-with-asp-net-identity-2/) that will show you how to implement it.

```
public async Task ImpersonateUserAsync(string userName)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;

    var originalUsername = context.User.Identity.Name;

    var impersonatedUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

    var impersonatedIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(impersonatedUser, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    impersonatedIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserImpersonation", "true"));
    impersonatedIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("OriginalUsername", originalUsername));

    var authenticationManager = context.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, impersonatedIdentity);
}
```

Extension method to detect impersonation:

```
public static bool IsImpersonating(this IPrincipal principal)
{
    if (principal == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var claimsPrincipal = principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
    if (claimsPrincipal == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return claimsPrincipal.HasClaim("UserImpersonation", "true");
}
```

Use the previous code like this:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsImpersonating())
{
    // do my stuff for admins
}
```

And revert back.

```
public async Task RevertImpersonationAsync()
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;

    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.IsImpersonating())
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to remove impersonation because there is no impersonation");
    }


    var originalUsername = HttpContext.Current.User.GetOriginalUsername();

    var originalUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(originalUsername);

    var impersonatedIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(originalUser, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    var authenticationManager = context.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

    authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, impersonatedIdentity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The marked answer is the 'right' way to do it I believe.  I just wanted to post another way which works as well.  This way the admin logs in using the user's email address, but they insert "___" in front of it (this isn't really needed, but I wanted the admins to have to do something different).  They then use the Master Password (which is hard-coded into the Account Controller, should be stored somewhere where it can be easily changed really).  The Login POST method (in the Account Controller) is then changed to:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        if ((model.Password == MasterPassword) && model.Email.StartsWith("___"))
        {
            var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email.Replace("___", ""));
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, true, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
    }
```

Not as slick as using impersonation, but works nonetheless.